# Dojo : Clear all textboxes of a div

Tags: dojo

How can I clear all the text boxes of a div from client side, in which the parent not contains any from tags.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you put a classname on the divs:

```
var nodes = dojo.query(".className");
for(var x = 0; x < nodes.length; x++)
{
   nodes[x].value = "";
// nodes[x].innerHMTL = ""; 
}
```

Or you may get the nodes with somethign like this:

var nodes = dojo.query("div>input[type='text']");

(I did not test :-/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding on unludo's answer (and if using dojo 1.7):

```
require(["dojo/query"], function(query){
  query("div > input[type='text']").forEach(function(node){
    node.value = "";
  });
});
```

if dojo < 1.7

```
dojo.query("div > input[type='text']").forEach(function(node){
        node.value = "";
      });
```